# Azure DevOps pipeline task to wait to run for another pipeline to complete

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I had a question regarding Azure DevOps pipelines and tasks and was wondering if anyone could help.

I have a pipeline with a task that runs a PowerShell script. This script kicks off a separate pipeline, but once that script is run, the original task returns a "pass" (as expected) and the next task in the original pipeline begins to run.

Ideally, I would like the next task in pipeline 1 to wait until the pipeline that was kicked off by the script is complete (and returns a pass). Does anyone know of a way this can be achieved? The steps are using YAML. So far I have seen conditions to wait for other steps in the same pipeline, but nothing to stop a step from running until a completely separate pipeline is completed (and passes successfully).

Hopefully I am making sense. I can provide screenshots if that would help as well!

Comment: Why is it a separate pipeline in the first place? If you're using YAML, you can break the pipelines into multiple files and have a separate job that uses the same steps.

Comment: Has the problem been solved? If so, please accept the solution as the answer so it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.If not,please feel free to tell.

Comment: Apologies, have been away for the week, answer below has been marked as solution! Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of trigger the build with your PowerShell script, you can install the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) extension and use it. there you have an option **Wait till the triggered builds are finished before build continues**:

[image]

In YAML:

```
- task: TriggerBuild@3
  displayName: 'Trigger a new build of Test'
  inputs:
    buildDefinition: Test
    waitForQueuedBuildsToFinish: true
    waitForQueuedBuildsToFinishRefreshTime: 60
```

> If this option is enabled, the script will wait until the all the queued builds are finished. Note: This can take a while depending on your builds and your build will not continue. If you only have one build agent you will even end up in a deadlock situation!

Answer (score 1):

According to the description, the whole process could be separated to four parts:

1. The task1 in Pipeline1 should trigger the task in Pipeline2 and if the task in Pipeline is not editable you might need to create a new task in it at last for next step usement
2. The last task in Pipeline2 should do something like create a txt file in a specific folder or any another things that could be detected by task2 in Pipeline1
3. The task2 in Pipeline1 should wait and listen if a txt file in the folder is created which means the Pipeline1 is completed successfully.
4. Run the task2

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you face here is that all variables are evaluated on queue with YAML.

You could do a few things like utilise an external service such as an Azure Storage Account. Doing this you could do other stuff like write comments or statuses from the pipeline into a text file and read the values into your first pipeline.

At the end of script 1 in pipeline 1:

```
Do {
   $File = check for storage account file
   if ($File) {
      $FileExists = $true
   }
} until ($FileExists)
```

At the end of your other pipeline

```
Do stuff
Write stuff to file
Upload file to storage account
```

If you just want to wait for completion you could use azure devops cli at the end of your first powershell step. This is a good link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ITOps-Talk-Blog/Get-Azure-Pipeline-Build-Status-with-the-Azure-CLI/ba-p/472104 . You could run your logic on the returned `status` or `result`